# Синтаксис cmd (dos)

Tags: windows, cmd, dos

Меня интересует строка

```
@if %1.==. (goto error) ELSE (goto restart)
```

а конкретно что значит `.==.` ? Я предполагаю, что это какое то сравнение, на как тут конкретно оно работает и с чем сравнивает я не знаю.

`%1` передаваемое имя, на сколько мне известно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это проверка, что значение переменной %1 есть пустая строка. Просто в батче нет возможности задать литералом пустую строку - если, скажем, как в любом языке, набрать две кавычки, то это будет именно литерал из двух кавычек. Потому к значению переменной добавляется точка, и результат сравнивается с точкой. Вместо точки мог быть любой не-служебный символ, и не обязательно после параметра, тот же самый эффект дало бы и

```
@if .%1==. (goto error) ELSE (goto restart)
```

Чтои где использовать - дело вкуса и пристрастий. Я, например, предпочитаю использовать обрамляющие кавычки:

```
@if '%1'=='' (goto error) ELSE (goto restart)
```